# Integrate IBM watson conversation api in python

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I have created a chatbot using Watson assistant(conversation api) on the ibm watson (created entity, entities, dialogs). Also I am able to chat with watson assistant.

1. if there is any integration so that I can send and receive message through terminal (preferred language python)?
2. if there is any integration so that I can send and receive message through my personal website?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SDK/API's to integrate your Watson Assistant with your personal website or run in localhost.

API Reference: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl

SDK for Watson API's- https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud